# Confirmation of Form Submission using jQuery

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I want to show an alert box before form submission.

If a user presses yes, then the form will submit, otherwise it wont.
Is there a solution using jQuery?

Comment: "I need help buddy !!!" etc is not welcome here on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use the javascript `confirm(message) : boolean` function by intercepting the submit event of html form.

```
$("#html_form").submit(function(e){
    if (!confirm("should i really submit"))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#yourform').submit(function(e) {
    if(!confirm('really submit the form?')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    // submit the form via ajax, e.g. via the forms plugin
    // http://jquery.malsup.com/form/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this post...

[Confirmation Posts Yes/No Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

May be this will help you out.