# Rails3: how to request a confirmation before performing a controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, confirmation, ujs

I'm struggling to find a simple solution to circumvent the deprecation of ":confirm" on submit_tag

After a click on a submit_tag, I want just to request a confirmation before proceeding with the execution of a controller action. If it is not confirmed, I want to do nothing.
I understand this is possible in UJS. I'm using Coffeescript.

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: I eventually realized that I could use the "data: => { confirm:..." option on the form_tag, rather than on the submit_tag and, although that doesn't seem very logical since the confirmation is supposed to take place at submit time, that works very well anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think `data-confirm` still works:

```
submit_tag "Save", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

Look here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, it doesn't in Rails3 for submit_tag. The bug has been reported here [link](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/315)

Comment: Oh, nevermind then. Didn't know about this issue. Maybe you should try to update your app to the latest Rails.

Comment: again, submit_tag doc is of no help since there's a bug.
So I would like to circumvent it with a UJS solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is a jquery/javascript question, not a Rails question.

This question, of requiring confirm for a form submission, has been asked many times on SO. Please see this answer:
[Confirmation of Form Submission using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421293/confirmation-of-form-submission-using-jquery)

Comment: Yes and no because this answer explains how to request confirmation but not how to proceed with the performing of a Rails controller action afterwards, or am I missing something ?

Comment: If you do not confirm the javascript popup, the form will not submit and the browser will stay on the same page. That is how default Rails data-confirm works, as well. If you do confirm the javascript popup, the form will submit. There is no need for extra logic in the controller.