# Make javascript alert Yes/No Instead of Ok/Cancel

Tags: javascript

```
function btnSelete_Click() {
    var strconfirm = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (strconfirm == true) {
        return true;
    }
}

<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" Onclientclick="return btnSelete_Click();" CssClass="cssbutton" />
```

How to create a yes/no/cancel alert box instead of ok/cancel alert box in Javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

Comment: You can't change default, confirm dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

These libraries create HTML elements that look and behave like a dialog box, allowing you to put anything you want (including form elements or video) in the dialog.

Answer (score 13):

In an attempt to solve a similar situation I've come across [this](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/vvjj8/) example and [adapted](http://jsfiddle.net/FredWFourie/ocyxhva0/1/) it. It uses [JQUERY UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) as Nikhil D suggested. Here is a look at the code:

HTML:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="button" id="box" value="Confirm the thing?" />
<div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#box').click(function buttonAction() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").html("Do you want to do the thing?");

  // Define the Dialog and its properties.
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Do the thing?",
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
      "Yes": function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        alert("Yes, do the thing");
      },
      "No": function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        alert("Nope, don't do the thing");
      }
    }
  });
});

$('#box').click(buttonAction);
```

I have a few more tweaks I need to do to make this example work for my application. Will update this if I see it fit into the answer.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do that with the native `confirm()` as it is the browser’s method.

You have to create a plugin for a confirm box (or try one created by someone else). And they often look better, too.

**Additional Tip**: Change your English sentence to something like

> Really, Delete this Thing?

Comment: End confirmation message something like "Press OK button to confirm."

Answer (score 2):

Built a tiny, confirm-like vanilla js yes / no dialog.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yesno-dialog

[image]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I shall try the solution with jQuery, for sure it should give a nice result. Of course you have to load jQuery ...
What about a pop-up with something like this? Of course this is dependant on the user authorizing pop-ups.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    var ret;
    function returnfunction()
    {
        alert(ret);
    }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label id="QuestionToAsk" name="QuestionToAsk">Here is talked.</label><br />
            <input type="button" value="Yes" name="yes" onClick="ret=true;returnfunction()" />
            <input type="button" value="No" onClick="ret=false;returnfunction()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Confirm" in Javascript stops the whole process until it gets a mouse response on its buttons. If that is what you are looking for, you can refer jquery-ui but if you have nothing running behind your process while receiving the response and you control the flow programatically, take a look at this. You will have to hard-code everything by yourself but you have complete command over customization. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp