# How to make confirm box have different buttons than cancel and ok

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to make an confrim box have different buttons than cancel and ok

```
function start(){ 

confirm ("Hello how are you")buttons("Fine", "Not good");

}
```

Comment: You can't. Create a custom modal. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google search, I found this [tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3) for creating a custom dialog box using Jquery.