# Javascript : custom text on Confirm Ok Cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a validation where i want to show 'Continue' and 'Return' instead of OK and Cancel but I am not able to find accurate solution, can anyone help me on this.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" style="font:10px;">
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                      javascript:
                      var amount = document.getElementById('txtboxAdjustment14').value.trim();
                      if(amount == 0)
                      {
                      var cont =confirm("Have you considered amount?")
                      if (cont == true)
                      {
                      somemethod();
                      }
                      else if(cont == false)
                      {
                      return false;
                      }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                      somemethod();
                      }
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </input>
```

Comment: You can't. You'll have to create your own dialog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the buttons in JavaScript dialog.

But you can try [**This**](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/) or [**This**](http://www.projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the buttons on the javascript confirm dialog.  You would need to use a custom dialog implementation such as the one contained in [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

Answer (score 0):

There's no decent cross-browser solution for doing that. I'd suggest you to use some library like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to build a custom OK-Cancel dialog.

Check out [this modal confirmation dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Comment: most of them have some event associated with buttons but I just want to customise text of message box(OK,Cancel -->Confirm,Return)

Comment: @Animesh: Sorry, you can't perform that kind of customization with the default message boxes. You'll have to use something custom-made. That's the only way.