# Customize the name of Popup window action buttons in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am using this code to add popup confirmation window on action button through jquery code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("table.shop_table.subscription_details a.cancel").on("click", function(e) {
    var doit = confirm("Are you sure you want to do it ?")
    if (!doit) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})
})
</script>
```

I am trying to figure out way to customize it so i can change the name of cancel and ok button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript : custom text on Confirm Ok Cancel button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420935/javascript-custom-text-on-confirm-ok-cancel-button)

Comment: I dont think so

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```html
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js
```

Just do

```html
<a href="somepage" class="confirm">Link to page</a>
```

And jquery

```js
$(".confirm").confirm();
```

For more options see:
https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Comment: its different from what i am asking actually! code above is already created, i need to add additional option of customizing the buttons text

Comment: I think this is not possible, because the confirm element is not rendered in the DOM. You have to do it with jquery confirm js oder with jquery ui dialog.