# Confirm Popup in ASP.NET with Yes No

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need a confirm popup which shows `Yes and No`

Now there is javascript `confirm` function which shows `OK Cancel` buttons and always gets displayed on the  top of the page.

Is there a Jquery function which shows `Yes/No` ?

Or at least is there a way to show the Javascript popup next to the button which makes it popup?

So far my search points to make a custom popup..

Note: the proposed link is not a duplicate: It does not answer part of my question which asks for making popup next the button.

Comment: You can check this library: http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/ and this: http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

Comment: You are correct - there is no native way for javascript to show `Yes/No` instead of `OK/Cancel`

Comment: look at jQuery UI Dialog - https://jqueryui.com/dialog/, it satisfies your requirements, although you have to code around different modality concept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

Comment: @Ozan Deniz : Understood, How about making it show next to the button? is that also impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're just trying to make a confirm modal that looks how you want it.

You'd basically just be including some HTML that's located where you want, and has its visibility toggled with the `$.toggle()` method.

Take a look at a simple example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/45ngrquo/1/).

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to modify the built-in alert() popup modal, because it's an actual system object, not just a design rendered in JS.