# Change confirm dialog box button's text in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui

First of all would like to mention that i am new in Angular JS. I have implemented below code in that i want to change button text (By default button names are "Ok" and "Cancel") .i.e "ok" button text to "Yes" and "cancel" button text to "No" without using modal popup. Is there any other way to implement this ? Its already compatible in all browser.

```
  $scope.sectionLoad = function (formId, sectionId, parentIndex, index){

        if(confirm("Save data?")){
                $scope.submit($scope.form, pageId, sectorId);
        }
        $scope.search = false;
        $scope.sectionDataLoad(formId, sectionId, parentIndex);

  };
```

Comment: Where is the template? Do you 3rd party modal dialog?

Comment: Lot of questions about this on stackoverflow ... Not able to tag ur question as duplicate from phone ... But search for "HTML confirm button label" ...

Comment: You cannot do that with the native confirm() as it is of browser's method. You can use custom modal directives, https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

Answer (score 0):

In short - you can't. There's no sure-fire way to change the buttons in a `confirm()` dialog. You need to create a custom dialog and use that in place of `confirm()`.

Comment: In angular-material.js  mentioned as  we can set custom message to confirm button:                                                                         $mdDialogPreset#ok(string) - Sets the confirm "Okay" button text.
 * - $mdDialogPreset#cancel(string) - Sets the confirm "Cancel" button text.

Comment: That would be a custom dialog you're referencing from angular-material.js. `confirm()` is the default JavaScript confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

$scope.loadData= function (Id, sectionId, parentIndex) {

```
                $.confirm({
                    title:"Save confirmation",
                    text: "Do you want to save the section data ?",
                    confirm: function (button) {
                        $scope.submit(Id, sectionId, parentIndex, index, 2);
                        $scope.search = false;
                        $scope.sectionLoad(Id, sectionId, parentIndex, index);
                        alert("Section Data Saved.");
                    },
                    cancel: function (button) {
                        $scope.sectionLoad(formId, sectionId, parentIndex, index);
                        alert("Section data not saved");
                    },
                    confirmButton: "Yes",
                    cancelButton: "No"
                });   
    };
```

Comment: Just we need to add jquery.confirm.js and jquery.confirm.min.js :-)