# Can i edit the buttons of a browser dialogs?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it's possible to change the text of the OK/Cancel buttons in dialogs?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

Answer (score 0):

there is not a part of html or css so you cannot change it anymore.
[here for refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 0):

possible but you need to create a custom alert dialog

https://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3

Answer (score 0):

You may with HTML5 which permits you to create your own customized dialog boxes, as the following example illustrates:

HTML:

```
<dialog open id="favDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <section>
      <p>Leave this site?</p>
    </section>
    <menu>
      <button id="cancel" type="reset">No</button>
      <button type="submit">Yes</button>
    </menu>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

See [live code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqwOMd)

This code to date is only supported by a couple of the major browsers, namely Chrome 37 and Opera 24 (see more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)).