# how to make a button a double check(cancel confirm) so no coincidence would happen

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button
that deletes the user info from my site
I want to add something(like an alert) that says
cancel...confirm
so no coincidence would possibly happen(deleting an user by coincidence)
pls help me thx

Comment: You can change the text of the button, and based on that (or a custom property that you add to button) on click you can do 2 different actions

Comment: You can add an alert on the onClick event listener for the same button maybe.

Comment: The first button can trigger a [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) and then you check the return value from the confirm box. Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ujoLkb8r/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Confirm popup Yes, No button instead of OK and Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823790/javascript-confirm-popup-yes-no-button-instead-of-ok-and-cancel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also add **your own css generated pop-ups**.

There's one thing special about these and that is these are customizable.As you create these pop up's on your own therfore you can add colors and shapes to it manually.

**And chosing a color is helpful as you can influence the users deicision based on colors.**

For example-
If you chose a red color for your delete button the user will bw warned towards that button as some kind of potential threat/negative step/action.

```js
popup = document.getElementById('popup'); // gets the popup element from the document
deleteBtn = document.getElementById('deleteBtn');
function confirmDelete() {
  //your code for deleting the user-details goes here
  hide();
  deleteBtn.style.display = 'Block';
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'Yor Details Have Been Successfully Deleted...';
  deleteBtn.onclick = '';
}

function show(){
  popup.style.display = 'Block';
  deleteBtn.style.display = 'None';
}

function hide(){
  popup.style.display = 'None';
  deleteBtn.style.display = 'Block';
}
```

```css
#popup{
  display: None;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px Solid Red;
  text-align: center;
}

#popupMessage{
  color: Red;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#deleteBtn{
  padding:5px;
  background-color: rgba(200,23,23,0.5);  //using shagdes of red also signals the user of a potentially negative step
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

#confirm{
  padding:5px;
  background-color: rgba(200,23,23,0.5);  //using shagdes of red also signals the user of a potentially negative step
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#cancel{
  color: rgba(255,25,255,1);
  padding:5px;
  background-color: rgba(20,255,23,0.5);  //using shagdes of green might signal the user of a potentially positive step
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!--code for the pop up -->
<div id='popup'>
  <span id='popupMessage'>Are you sure you want to delete your details..?</span><br/>
  <button id='confirm' onclick='confirmDelete()'>Confirm</button>
  <button id='cancel' onclick='hide()'>Cancel</button>
</div>
<!---->

<!--code for the delete button-->
<button id='deleteBtn' onclick='show()'>Delete</button>
<!---->
```

**Thanks as your question helped me learn newer concepts.**

I had previously anwered this question which had enough information on what you asked and that answer was helpfully modified by the moderators,meanwhile i thought i should learn something about creating own pop up's so i came up with this new answer.Hope it helps...Happy coding..:)

Comment: hello
there is a problem
when i press cancel it still deletes the user info ( it excutes the same order wether you press cancel or ok ) 
can you explain it too?

Comment: @holyblast it shouldn't delete the details on pressing cancel, Have you added the deletion code in the cancel buttons onclick event too..? can i please have a peek at your code..?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `confirm()` method for throwing a pop up box and asking the user if they are sure to delete the information.

For example:

```js
const confirmation = confirm('Are you sure to delete all the information..?') ; 
if (confirmation) {
  //code to delete the user information goes here
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan thanks..! i didn't knew about the confirm() method.Thanks for pointing it out and making it obvious. I just learned about that and i think i'll edit the answer thanks to you.Hooray..!

Comment: @mplungjan sorry sir... now i have no idea of how to remove that variable except for if we were passing the return value to the deletion function itself...And as much as i could learn about confirm() i just learnt that it can take just a message, i don't see a way to associate a function with it. Can you please edit my answer? It will help me too...

Answer (score 1):

1. Using a button not in a form

```js
document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    console.log("Deleting");
    // code to delete
  }
  else {
    console.log("Cancelled");
  }
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="delete">Delete</button>
```

2. Using a submit button in a form

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    console.log("Deleting");
    // form is submitting here
  }
  else {
    console.log("Cancelled");
    e.preventDefault(); // cancelling submission
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="delete">
<button>Delete</button>
</form>
```